MySQL group by giving different total results based on level of aggregation
I have a mysql table with multiple categorical columns (calendar day, country, marketing channels, etc) and several numerical columns that represent metrics relevant for that combination of categorical columns (i.e. number of new orders on that day in this country that came in through organic search, etc).
The problem I sometimes run into and cannot understand why is that when I aggregate data from this table, I get different results based on how many levels of aggregation I use.
e.g. a simple sum:
select
sum(orders)
from calendar_table;

gives a different result than the following query:
select
  DATE_FORMAT(calendar_day, '%Y-%m') as calendar_month,
  country,
  sum(orders)
from calendar_table
group by calendar_month, country;

By different results I mean that the total sum of orders in query 2 is higher than that of query 1.
The mysql database runs a InnoDB engine, the table has around 300k rows, no indices (it is an analytical table already built from production data and other sources).
What could be the reason for this mismatch?
I have cross checked the data from one of the source tables to know what the "correct" values should be. And I know that the first query (no group by, just a sum() query) gives the correct value. But the grouping queries just break it down.

MySQL usually doesn't lie.  Add the expected output.

To debug add with rollup to second query , add a validation check in first query for calendar month, run first query individually for every country.

sometimes it returns the following: https://ibb.co/xL0ybyw
so clearly a random and wrong result.
first query for each country works OK (with where country='XX' condition).
when I add the rollup option to group by, the results come back correct (totals and individual sums).

so in summary:
sum(x) without group by works ok.
group by with rollup works ok.
group by without rollup throws random numbers.

The linked image doesn't appear to be from either query , so is there something else other than mysql being used here?

OK so I figured it out myself. The problem was with data types. The columns that were throwing the problem were float columns.
after changing the data to decimal the issue is resolved.
